# I am using Mockito framework 1.9.0 . While using Mathchers in Mockito I am getting following errors

Tags: java, mockito

I am using Mockito framework 1.9.0 . In my test cases I have a code

```
when(buildRequest(storageMock,eq(ClientResourceListWrapper.class),eq(new String[]{"/resources"}),any(ErrorHandler.class))).thenReturn(resourcerequestMock);
```

This gives a error as

> Invalid use of argument matchers! 0 matchers expected, 3 recorded. This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values: //incorrect: someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example: //correct: someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

Answer (score 0):

Well the error says exactly that the problem is; from what I can see you've combined matchers with raw values. Just change it to:

```
when(buildRequest(eq(storageMock),eq(ClientResourceListWrapper.class),eq(new String[]{"/resources"}),any(ErrorHandler.class))).thenReturn(resourcerequestMock);
```